# Multiple page includes dynamic url PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to have a multiple page include. For example:

[www.website.com/?page=brewery&name=heineken&section=manage&subsection=beesr&action=create](http://www.website.com/?page=brewery&name=heineken&section=manage&subsection=beesr&action=create)

Basically, there will be a brewery page for said brewery, and a manage page for admins. If user is admin, they can view manage page > view beers > create beer.

I've tried doing a page include script below on each page (brewery, manage, beer), but it gives me a fatal error.

Is there anyway to merge 5 parameters into one file, say brewery?

Below is example code:

````
    // Allowed pages
    $pages = array(
    'main',
    'range',
    'manage'
    );

    // Check if page is empty
    if (!isset($_GET['section'])) {
        include('pages/brewery/main.php');
    } else {
    
        // Check file format
        if (strpos($_GET['section'], '.') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
            include('pages/brewery/main.php');
        } else {
        
            // Check if file exists
            if (!file_exists(sprintf('pages/brewery/%s.php', $_GET['section']))) {
                header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                include('pages/brewery/main.php');
            } else {
            
                // If page is allowed - incude
                if (in_array($_GET['section'], $pages)) {
                    include('pages/brewery/' . $_GET['section'] . '.php');

                
                    // Check if the page is not allowed
                    } else {
                    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                    include('pages/brewery/main.php');
            
            } // Close check if the page is not allowed
        } // Close check of file exists
    } // Close check file format
} // Close check if page is empty
?>```
````

Comment: instead of include use location.href = "your page path here";

Comment: Please click [edit] under the question, and add the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: As a tip unrelated to your problem, `else { if( ...) {` can be written `elseif(...) {` and then you don't need so many levels of nesting.